# is there a pandas function to create a df of an dict object inside a df

Tags: python, pandas

So now I have a .csv file which is a df.to_csv stuff and It looks like this

| APPL | US | blahblahblah | {'open':someting....} |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

I want to ask if there's someway to merge that dict stuff into the df.
You can find the whole csv file [here](https://img.fla.si/stock.csv)

Here is my code

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from requests import api

params = {
    'access_key': 'YOUR_ACCESS_KEY'
}

api_result = requests.get(
    'http://api.marketstack.com/v1/tickers/aapl/eod', params)

api_response = api_result.json()
df = pd.DataFrame([api_response['data']][0])
# df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame((df['eod'][:])[0])], axis=1) # df['eod'][:] is the dict
df.to_csv('stock.csv')
```

Comment: There are two `eod` columns, according to the data. Which would should the keys be extracted out of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to convert `dict` data to Series of pandas by each key.

There is so strong function in pandas. that is `.apply()`. You can use this function for each row/column.

In this case, you can use `.apply(pd.Series)` to convert data.

this is example code.

```py
import pandas as pd

# read your csv file
df = pd.read_csv('stock.csv')

# your csv has two "eod" column that has same data, so I drop last eod column.
# if you want to use all eod columns, then make your on solution using below code.
# drop unexpected columns
df = df.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0', 'eod.1'])

# apply(eval): To change the data of "eod" column from "str" type to "dict" type
# apply(pd.Series): To make pd.DataFrame from one Series with dict data
df2 = df['eod'].apply(eval).apply(pd.Series)

# merge origin df and new df2
result_df = pd.merge(df, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)

# drop eod column, because we don't need "eod" column, anymore.
result_df = result_df.drop(columns='eod')

print(result_df)
```

You need change some line for the data from api server.
maybe,, your `stock.csv` data is not equal with data from api server.